# Update Entity for Repository Pattern and UOW Pattern C#

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, architectural-patterns, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

In one mock solution, I have created 3 mock projects to implement layered architecture design mainly the - Presentation Layer (Web) - Domain Model Layer - Infrastructure Layer. I haven't yet to add Application Service Layer (Web API).

For simplicity, I have only two domain model entities: Customer.cs and Category.cs. In my domain model layer, I also put my repository interface (both custom and generic).

In Infrastructure layer, I have the dbcontext, Unit of Work (including its interface) and repository classes (which implement repository interface).

[image]

Here is my generic repository interface

```
public interface IRepositoryGeneric<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    // CRD
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Get(object Id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void Save();
}
```

Generic Repository class

```
public class RepositoryGeneric<T> : IRepositoryGeneric<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly AppDbContext db;
    public RepositoryGeneric(AppDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public T Get(object Id)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Find(Id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Remove(entity);

    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Unit of Work Interface

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepositoryCustomer Customers { get; }
    IRepositoryCategory Categories { get; }

    int Save();
}
```

Unit of Work Class

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly AppDbContext db;
    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        db = new AppDbContext();
    }

    private IRepositoryCustomer _Customers;
    public IRepositoryCustomer Customers
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._Customers == null)
            {
                this._Customers = new RepositoryCustomer(db);
            }
            return this._Customers;
        }
    }

    private IRepositoryCategory _Categories;
    public IRepositoryCategory Categories
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Categories == null)
            {
                _Categories = new RepositoryCategory(db);
            }
            return _Categories;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I learned that I should not have the update method in my generic repository interface. But without update method, I am now stuck at edit method in my presentation MVC web controller. Below, I extracted just the edit action method. The error is in that line in bold.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CategoryID,CategoryName,Description")] Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            **db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;**
            db.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(category);
    }
```

Lastly, are my classes created in the right layer? Example should IUnitOfWork.cs be in Infrastructure layer?

My whole solution source is available at my github - https://github.com/ngaisteve1/LayeredArchitectureDesignCSharp

Comment: I don't know where you heard that you can't have an edit or update method in your repository, but **you can.**  Problem solved.  In fact, your `Save()` method is effectively an update.

Comment: Sorry,  I mean how do I track the state changes before save?

Comment: Finally, I fixed state changes issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic Repository interface

```
public interface IRepositoryGeneric<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    // CRD
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Get(object Id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void UpdateState(TEntity entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Repository generic class

```
public class RepositoryGeneric<T> : IRepositoryGeneric<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly AppDbContext db;
    public RepositoryGeneric(AppDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public T Get(object Id)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Find(Id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Remove(entity);

    }

    public void UpdateState(T entity)
    {
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Web Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CategoryID,CategoryName,Description")] Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Categories.UpdateState(category);
            db.Commit();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(category);
    }
```

Comment: The quality of this answer would be much improved by an explanation of what has been changed and why.